# Are these polynomials irreducible over ring Z of integers ?

Tags: polynomials, factorization

Is it true that polynomials of the form :

> $ f(x)= x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x^{k+1}+ax^k+ax^{k-1}+...a$
>
> where $gcd(n+1,k+1)=1$ and $ a\in  \mathbb{Z^{+}} $

are irreducible over ring $\mathbb{Z} $ of integers ?

Neither of  [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) and [Cohn's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) cannot be applied on the polynomials of this form. I have checked a lot of cases and it seems to be true.

Comment: Did you mean to exclude a=1? If not, this will not be irreducible whenever n+1 is composite.

Comment: Counterexample: $x^2 + 4x + 4$.

Comment: @Carnahan,what if a is odd and greater than 1

Comment: The third example is with $a=21$ pedja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want $a \ne 1$.

I suppose no, here are some examples:

$$ x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1 = (x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} + 1) $$
$$ x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 6 = (x + 2) \cdot (x^{2} - x + 3) $$
$$ x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 21 = (x + 3) \cdot (x^{2} - 2x + 7) $$
$$ x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 52 = (x + 4) \cdot (x^{2} - 3x + 13) $$
$$ x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1 = (x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} + 1) $$
$$ x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 12 = (x^{2} - 2x + 3) \cdot (x^{2} + 3x + 4) $$
$$ x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + 12x + 12 = (x + 2) \cdot (x^{3} - x^{2} + 3x + 6) $$
$$ x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 1 = (x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} - x + 1) \cdot (x^{2} + x + 1) $$
$$ x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x^{2} + x + 22 = (x + 2) \cdot (x^{4} - x^{3} + 3x^{2} - 5x + 11) $$

Comment: you are right.what if $ a_1 \neq 1 $ and $a$ is odd number greater than $1$ ?

Comment: You mean $k>1$ and $a>1$ odd ? There is an example with $a=21$

Comment: no, $a_1$ is coefficient of the linear term...example: $ x^2+3x+3 $ where $ a_1=a=3 $

Comment: in example above $a_0=a=21$

Comment: $x^3+x^2+x+21$ is odd >1

Comment: Do you want $k>1$ ?

Comment: yes but $a_1=1$ and I am asking what if $a_1=a >1$

Comment: yes $k$ must be greater than $1$

Comment: pedja, I think at this point the onus is on you to either find an example yourself or to give some reason why you think there may not be one. Otherwise, I can see an infinity of questions...what if $a_2\gt1$? what if $a_3\gt1$?... what if $a_{73}\gt1089$? 